# Unable to install windows 7 after deletion of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows-7

I bought a laptop HP 8460p which already have pre installed windows 10, then I install ubuntu 18.04 by create a root partition on ext4, However I had some bios issue therefore I sent it for repair when its came back the both OS were deleted, Now I tried to install windows on the laptop but when its come on partition select page it says "Cannot install windows on this partition" I tried several ways like gparted or make an windows ISO by GPT but nothing works.

Now the situation is I have 128GB SSD hard drive which have only one root partition and ultemately only have ubuntu on it. Please help me to get back my laptop on dual boot and install windows properply.

Comment: You'll probably need to clean the disk before the Windows installer will recognize it and allow installation. The disk management utility in the Windows installer is likely unable to perform the necessary action.

Comment: If you're installing in UEFI mode, GPT is required. If Legacy then MBR. You can boot a live session Ubuntu and use GParted to adjust accordingly: Use Device > New partition table and choose all the settings accordingly. This will remove all partitions. Then the Windows installer should work. Of course, and again, you need to choose GPT or "msdos" (MBR) depending on the installation method and how you boot the installer is what determines the installation method. You may want to adjust UEFI settings for the desired outcome.

Comment: You should delete all partitions on the disk, then select the unallocated partition, as the partition you want to install Windows to.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure, that usually works unless there's a requirements mismatch as commented above. OP apparently already deleted the partitions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes I think this GParted thing gonna work

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to delete the partitions but with windows installer method not with GPart let me try this one as well

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - If the partition has Ubuntu on it, then the author has NOT done my suggestion, and delete all partitions on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

ext4 is the default filesystem format in Ubuntu 18.04, but Windows is expecting a partition that is formatted as NTFS. Otherwise the Windows installer will stop and not continue, because it does not recognize your laptop's ext4 formatted hard drive. To solve this problem boot the laptop from the live DVD/USB that you used to install Ubuntu 18.04. You may need to set the USB flash drive as first in the [boot sequence in the BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority/1084586#1084586), so your laptop will be able to boot from it. Open the built-in GParted partition editor application, and create an NTFS partition for Windows 7.

Now your laptop is ready to install Windows. When you boot the Windows 7 installer after creating an NTFS partition, the Windows installer will recognize it and the Windows 7 installation will proceed normally.

Comment: If the disk is not GPT they still won't be able to install Windows on the new partition.